EC2 issues with routing in Next.js 14: navigating to "/" causes a hard refresh + going to "/about" page yields error
Note that "/" is the only link that causes a hard refresh. The others all work as intended by navigating smoothly and without causing a hard refresh. For now, a live version of the site can be found here: https://james5.weakerpotions.com
The EC2 instance is sitting behind a Cloudfront distribution.
Entering https://james5.weakerpotions.com/about directly into the URL bar yields the following error output instead of the desired HTML:
2:I[7831,[],""]
3:I[4155,["1","static/chunks/1-b85273fb24ba92ff.js","749","static/chunks/749-453bd42f5b15cc53.js","712","static/chunks/712-c0d261fd7142231d.js","301","static/chunks/app/about/page-0d47dcd370a54038.js"],""]
4:I[5613,[],""]
5:I[1778,[],""]
6:I[8539,["1","static/chunks/1-b85273fb24ba92ff.js","712","static/chunks/712-c0d261fd7142231d.js","185","static/chunks/app/layout-6b2232b6fa2df148.js"],""]
7:I[8212,["1","static/chunks/1-b85273fb24ba92ff.js","749","static/chunks/749-453bd42f5b15cc53.js","931","static/chunks/app/page-cf6577c96c433d55.js"],""]
0:["zs5Vzl_sRLDC-tKyobmUW",[[["",{"children":["about",{"children":["__PAGE__",{}]}]},"$undefined","$undefined",true],["",{"children":["about",{"children":["__PAGE__",{},["$L1",["$","$L2",null,{"propsForComponent":{"params":{}},"Component":"$3","isStaticGeneration":true}],null]]},["$","$L4",null,{"parallelRouterKey":"children","segmentPath":["children","about","children"],"loading":"$undefined","loadingStyles":"$undefined","loadingScripts":"$undefined","hasLoading":false,"error":"$undefined","errorStyles":"$undefined","errorScripts":"$undefined","template":["$","$L5",null,{}],"templateStyles":"$undefined","templateScripts":"$undefined","notFound":"$undefined","notFoundStyles":"$undefined","styles":null}]]},[null,["$","html",null,{"lang":"en","children":["$","$L6",null,{"children":["$","body",null,{"className":"__className_aaf875","children":[["$","$L7",null,{}],["$","$L4",null,{"parallelRouterKey":"children","segmentPath":["children"],"loading":"$undefined","loadingStyles":"$undefined","loadingScripts":"$undefined","hasLoading":false,"error":"$undefined","errorStyles":"$undefined","errorScripts":"$undefined","template":["$","$L5",null,{}],"templateStyles":"$undefined","templateScripts":"$undefined","notFound":[["$","title",null,{"children":"404: This page could not be found."}],["$","div",null,{"style":{"fontFamily":"system-ui,\"Segoe UI\",Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif,\"Apple Color Emoji\",\"Segoe UI Emoji\"","height":"100vh","textAlign":"center","display":"flex","flexDirection":"column","alignItems":"center","justifyContent":"center"},"children":["$","div",null,{"children":[["$","style",null,{"dangerouslySetInnerHTML":{"__html":"body{color:#000;background:#fff;margin:0}.next-error-h1{border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3)}@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark){body{color:#fff;background:#000}.next-error-h1{border-right:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3)}}"}}],["$","h1",null,{"className":"next-error-h1","style":{"display":"inline-block","margin":"0 20px 0 0","padding":"0 23px 0 0","fontSize":24,"fontWeight":500,"verticalAlign":"top","lineHeight":"49px"},"children":"404"}],["$","div",null,{"style":{"display":"inline-block"},"children":["$","h2",null,{"style":{"fontSize":14,"fontWeight":400,"lineHeight":"49px","margin":0},"children":"This page could not be found."}]}]]}]}]],"notFoundStyles":[],"styles":null}]]}]}]}],null]],[[["$","link","0",{"rel":"stylesheet","href":"/_next/static/css/07e595db8829ab47.css","precedence":"next","crossOrigin":""}]],"$L8"]]]]
8:[["$","meta","0",{"name":"viewport","content":"width=device-width, initial-scale=1"}],["$","meta","1",{"charSet":"utf-8"}],["$","title","2",{"children":"Home | James Shapiro"}],["$","meta","3",{"name":"description","content":"Homepage of James Shapiro"}],["$","link","4",{"rel":"icon","href":"/icon.png?c784c04ea7a32b19","type":"image/png","sizes":"700x700"}],["$","meta","5",{"name":"next-size-adjust"}]]
1:null

Navigation component is as follows:
'use client';
import React from 'react';
import { LayoutGroup, motion } from 'framer-motion';
import Link from 'next/link';

import styled from 'styled-components';

function Navigation() {
  const [hoveredNavItem, setHoveredNavItem] = React.useState(null);

  const id = React.useId();

  return (
    <nav onMouseLeave={() => setHoveredNavItem(null)}>
      <ul>
        {LINKS.map(({ slug, label, bg, href }) => (
          <li
            key={slug}
            style={{
              zIndex: hoveredNavItem === slug ? 1 : 2,
            }}
          >
            {hoveredNavItem === slug && (
              <motion.div
                layoutId={id}
                className="hovered-backdrop"
                initial={{
                  borderRadius: 8,
                }}
              />
            )}

            <Link href={href} onMouseEnter={() => setHoveredNavItem(slug)}>
              {label}
            </Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}

const LINKS = [
  {
    slug: 'home',
    label: 'Home',
    href: '/',
  },
  {
    slug: 'about',
    label: 'About',
    href: '/about/',
  },
  {
    slug: 'projects',
    label: 'Projects',
    href: '/projects/',
  },
  {
    slug: 'rants',
    label: 'Rants',
    href: '/rants/',
  },
];

export default Navigation;

I also have the following:
app/layout.js:
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';
import './globals.css';
import Navigation from '@/components/Navigation';

import StyledComponentsRegistry from './registry'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] });

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Home | James Shapiro',
  description: 'Homepage of James Shapiro',
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <StyledComponentsRegistry>
        <body className={inter.className}>
          <Navigation />
          {children}
        </body>
      </StyledComponentsRegistry>
      
    </html>
  );
}

app/page.js:
import Image from 'next/image';
import styles from './page.module.css';
import Navigation from '@/components/Navigation';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
    </>
  );
}

app/registry.js:
'use client';

import React from 'react';
import { useServerInsertedHTML } from 'next/navigation';
import {
  ServerStyleSheet,
  StyleSheetManager,
} from 'styled-components';

export default function StyledComponentsRegistry({
  children,
}) {
  const [styledComponentsStyleSheet] = React.useState(
    () => new ServerStyleSheet()
  );

  useServerInsertedHTML(() => {
    const styles = styledComponentsStyleSheet.getStyleElement();
    styledComponentsStyleSheet.instance.clearTag();
    return <>{styles}</>;
  });

  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') return <>{children}</>;

  return (
    <StyleSheetManager sheet={styledComponentsStyleSheet.instance}>
      {children}
    </StyleSheetManager>
  );
}

